# How do Puma threads interact with Postgres connection pools?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, postgresql, openshift, puma

I have a Rails app running on OSE, 5 pods, 1 container per pod. The Rails app uses the Puma web server with default thread settings (min: 0, max: 16). In my database.yml I've defined a connection `pool:` of 10.

I'd like to know what my maximum PG connection footprint would be?

My current theory is:

`5 pods` x `1 container` x `16 threads` x `10 connection pool` = `800 possible PostgreSQL connections`.

However, I'm questioning if each of the 16 Puma threads share from the same PG connection pool? In which case the formula would be:

`5 pods` x `1 container` x `10 connection pool` = `50 possible PostgreSQL connections`.

(Of course, having Puma 16 threads if this math is correct would be a problem since my app might *request* more connections than could be provided, at 1 per thread, 6 more than the pool offers.)

Can anyone point me to definitive documentation on the subject? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the connection pool is within the process and doles out database connections across threads, with threads waiting if all database connections busy, then the second is correct. If not, the first. Either way it can actually be worse though. If you are using rolling deployments, on a restart there could be one additional pod active.

Have a look at using pgbouncer (https://pgbouncer.github.io/) in front of the PostgreSQL database instance. My understanding is that it provides additional flexibility in being able to manage a pool of database connections without needing to do anything in your application, instead it is dealt with in pgbouncer.